# Is it standard practice to delete or comment out the code within an overridable function of a base class?

Tags: vb.net, oop

I spent 45 minutes arguing with my teacher about this today, and it seems stupid to me but maybe she just wasn't explaining it well.

She was trying to tell me that I one should comment out or delete the code block within an overridable function of the parent class when you make a child class with a function that overrides it.

Is there anything to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not. Just because one class overrides it doesn't mean that other classes that inherit from the base class would do the same. So in those cases you definitely want the base class functionality to remain there.

And then there is the point that dotNET has already made (child class needing to call base class's function to reuse the functionality already present there)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Helps to clarify a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> She was trying to tell me that I one should comment out or delete the code block within an overridable function of the parent class when you make a child class with a function that overrides it.

Lol wut?

- What if the overriding method needs to call the overridable method?
- What if another subclass is added that does not override the overridable method?
- What if someone wants to call the overridable from its own (non-abstract) class?

That's a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mean VB6 here. VB6 doesn't support true OOP. In VB.NET or C# though, the answer is certainly not. So often it is the case that an overridden function of the child class needs to calls the functionality of the base class before or after doing its actions. So I can't see why your teacher is making it a generic rule.

Comment: Ah yes I do mean VB.NET. I probably should have known that. Thanks for your answer. Glad she's wrong and not me.

Comment: @AName: One thing though: 45 minutes are just too much to spend on a point that simple, so I suspect she may have meant something else and it may just be a communication gap. You should consider engaging with her again in the light of all these answers.

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think so. I might take your advice, but it would probably result in another earful of crap. I'll see how I feel about it tomorrow. Thanks again.